# Audio device does not change

Tags: sound, headphones, 20.10

I have experiencing a strange issue with audio on 20.10
It has been working fine until yesterday, where I changed the audio device in settings from my Logitech G935 headphones to the built-in soundcard on my desktop PC.
Later in the evening I switched back, but audio still played on the speakers connected to the onboard sound card.
Just to be sure that it was not an issue with the headphones, I connected my old Logitech H390 and set this as the default audio output device, but still audio played on the speakers.
Applications with seperate audio configuration, such as Microsoft Teams, Skype and Zoom, do still work with the headset and plays audio through them.

When audio is playing it follows the volume of the speakers and not the currently selected output device. switching the audio device to the speakers, adjustment the volumne works

The system dual-boots with Windows 10, so I also checked there, but there is no issue.

How do I go about finding the cause of this

Comment: Audio volume control does also not work

Comment: Please add the extra info to the question that may help someone to help you.